# cffi module built but not found on import

Tags: python, python-3.x, cffi

I'm building a python package (end goal for pypi distribution) that relies on a C library. I have cffi included in my setup.py --
`cffi_modules=['my_package/my_build/build.py:ffibuilder'],`
which successfully compiles these files when I call `setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` ---
`_c_my_package.o
_c_my_package.c
_c_my_package.cpython-37m-darwin.so`
(and, in the wheel, `_c_my_package.abi3.so` - but I don't want to use ABI functionality)

However, when I `pip install my_package` (works fine) and then from the interpreter I `>>>import my_package` I get told: 
`no module named _c_my_package`

NB: when I `pip install -e /locallocation/my_package` , it will import the compiled c scripts as modules.

How do I prepare these modules properly for importing?

cffi 1.11.5, python3.7

Comment: Well, it's ... I have a fix if I just change my build.py such that the files come out as  _my_package.c/o/so instead of the _cpackage.o/c/so that was coming before, then they seem to enter the namespace JUST FINE. HOWEVER that requires a build to be run to build the three .c .o .so files. When I upload to test.pypi a new problem arises of needing to run setup.py or the libraries aren't built.